# Database structure for a tooth chart

Tags: database, database-design

Hello I'm not sure if this is an OK question here but here goes, I'm quite confused on how am I going to make the data structure of my tooth chart database.  I had first this thought of making a data structure like this

```
teeth_table 
teeth_id (Primary key)
teeth_1 (These are 32 tooth)
until teeth_32 (These are 32 tooth)
patient_id (Foreign key connected to the patient table)
```

my second plan is to make an individual table for each tooth (which will take a lot of time I guess?)

```
tooth01_table
tooth_id
tooth_name
tooth_condition
tooth_recommendation
tooth_treatment
patient_id
```

and that's all I thought,
my plan is to make a table where it would show the following when a patient selects a tooth from a dropdown list

Tooth | Condition | Recommendation | Treatment

So what do you guys think is a good design for a tooth chart database?

a tooth chart is like these

> http://www.mouthandteeth.com/img/FDI-tooth-numbering-system.gif

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend the following design:

```
CREATE TABLE tooth (
  tooth_code   char(2)     NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  -- teeth don't have real numbers
  -- it is a qudrant number + tooth number combination
  -- therefore char(2)
  tooth_cat   varchar(50) NOT NULL
    CHECK (tooth_cat IN ('incisor','canine','premolar','molar')
  -- though I find this info redundant,
  -- category can be deduced from tooth_code
);

CREATE TABLE mounth (
  patient_id   int4     NOT NULL,
  tooth_code   char(2)  NOT NULL,
  inspect_dt   timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
  condition    text,
  suggestion   text,
  treatment    text,
  PRIMARY KEY (patient_id, tooth_code, inspect_dt),
  FOREIGN KEY (patient_id) REFERENCES patient,
  FOREIGN KEY (tooth_code) REFERENCES tooth
);
```

1. you should have a dictionary with teeth codes and surronding description
2. each tooth belongs to some patient, therefore they should always go together
3. also, entry in the system appears during inspection, therefore PK consists of 3 columns for table `mouth`
4. I used `tooth_code`, 'cos `id` typically means numeric value, yet we don't have real number here, although they look alike
5. I don't quite like `mouth`, maybe `patient_inspections` or similar will be a better match.
6. English is not my native language, so pick better names where applicable.